# Using different axis scales in seaborn replot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I used this example from the [Seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot) to produce the figure below.

```py
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.relplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day", col="time", data=tips)
```

[image]

How can I force either the x- or y-axis to use different scales (for example have x range from (0, 100) in the right subplot)?

I tried passing `sharex=False` to the replot function, but that is not a valid keyword.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `facet_kws=` to pass the argument to the `FacetGrid` object. You can then change the limits by referencing each Axes using `g.axes` which is a 2D array of Axes objects.

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.relplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day", col="time", data=tips, facet_kws=dict(sharex=False))
g.axes[0,0].set_xlim(0,100)
g.axes[0,1].set_xlim(20,30)
```

[image]